# how to convert a dataframe of counts to a probability density function

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Suppose that I have the following observations of integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'observed_scores': [100, 100, 90, 85, 100, ...]})
```

I know that this can be used as an input to make a density plot:

```
df['observed_scores'].plot.density()
```

but suppose that what I have is a counts table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'observed_scores': [100, 95, 90, 85, ...], 'counts': [1534, 1399, 3421, 8764, ...})
```

which is cheaper to store than the full `observed_scores` Series (I have LOTS of observations).

I know it's possible to plot the histogram using the counts, but how do I plot the density plot? If possible, can it be done without having to unstack/unravel the counts table into thousands of rows?

Comment: Can you post a rough graph as to what it should look like?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703149/weights-option-for-seaborn-distplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, `statsmodels` lets you fit a weighted KDE:

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kde import KDEUnivariate

df = pd.DataFrame({'observed_scores': [100, 95, 90, 85],
                   'counts': [1534, 1399, 3421, 8764]})

kde1= KDEUnivariate(df.observed_scores)
kde_noweight = KDEUnivariate(df.observed_scores)
kde1.fit(weights=df.counts, fft=False)
kde_noweight.fit()
plt.plot(kde1.support, kde1.density)
plt.plot(kde_noweight.support, kde_noweight.density)
plt.legend(['weighted', 'unweighted'])
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: This is still histogram plot, not really a density function.

Comment: You're right  @QuangHoang, my bad! I edited correspondingly

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the weighted `kde` manually using scipy. This will match perfectly so long as you specify a `bw_method` as a scalar. When allowing the default, the fitting becomes inconsitent

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(410112)
# Real counts data to check with
df = pd.DataFrame({'observed_scores': np.random.randint(1, 100, 40000)})

# Aggregated to value_counts, which is what you have access to
df1 = df.groupby('observed_scores').size().to_frame('counts').reset_index()
```

---

#### Code

```
def weighted_kde(y, weights, bw_method=None):
    sample_range = np.nanmax(y) - np.nanmin(y)
    ind = np.linspace(
        np.nanmin(y) - 0.5 * sample_range,
        np.nanmax(y) + 0.5 * sample_range,
        1000)

    gkde = stats.gaussian_kde(y, bw_method=bw_method, weights=weights)

    y = gkde.evaluate(ind)
    
    return ind, y
```

---

#### Check output

```
bw_method=0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Underlying data, with pandas kde
df['observed_scores'].plot.density(ax=ax, bw_method=bw_method, label='pandas density', lw=2)

# From aggregated counts data
ind, y = weighted_kde(df1['observed_scores'], df1['counts'], bw_method=bw_method)
ax.plot(ind, y, label='Manual Weighted KDE', lw=2, linestyle='--')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see, so weighted KDE is the answer. Any idea though why I have to set the bandwidth manually? I usually rely on the built-in reference models to get the best value for the bandwidth.

Comment: @irene I'm not sure why there's the inconsistency. They *should* both do the same thing with the default, since my function is just the pandas source code, but I must be missing something pandas else is doing to choose the bw if it's not specified. That or there's a difference with the spicy versioning between my version and the one pandas was using. You can still use `bw_method=None` or `'scott'`, which will let scipy choose the appropriate bw. It might just not look like the default pandas might choose, though I don't think that's really an issue.